# Should one drain a buffered channel when closing it

Tags: go, channel

Given a (partially) filled buffered channel in Go

```
ch := make(chan *MassiveStruct, n)
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    ch <- NewMassiveStruct()
}
```

is it advisable to also drain the channel when closing it (by the writer) in case it is unknown when readers are going to read from it (e.g. there is a limited number of those and they are currently busy)? That is

```
close(ch)
for range ch {}
```

Is such a loop guaranteed to end if there are other concurrent readers on the channel?

**Context**: a queue service with a fixed number of workers, which should drop processing anything queued when the service is going down (but not necessarily being GCed right after). So I am closing to indicate to the workers that the service is being terminated. I could drain the remaining "queue" immediately letting the GC free the resources allocated, I could read and ignore the values in the workers and I could leave the channel as is running down the readers and setting the channel to nil in the writer so that the GC cleans up everything. I am not sure which is the cleanest way.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the logic in your program. Closing a channel is not a cleanup operation, and a buttered channel doesn't need to be empty to be GC'ed, so neither of these are required.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are better ways to achieve what you're trying to achieve. Your current approach can just lead to throwing away some records, and processing other records randomly (since the draining loop is racing all the consumers). That doesn't really address the goal.

What you want is cancellation. Here's an example from [Go Concurrency Patterns: Pipelines and cancellation](http://blog.golang.org/pipelines)

```
func sq(done <-chan struct{}, in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        for n := range in {
            select {
            case out <- n * n:
            case <-done:
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    return out
}
```

You pass a `done` channel to all the goroutines, and you close it when you want them all to stop processing. If you do this a lot, you may find the `golang.org/x/net/context` package useful, which formalizes this pattern, and adds some extra features (like timeout).

Comment: I use this pattern right now and will stick to it. After all it feels the only thing I need to do is to set the channel to nil in the publisher so that after the workers are terminated, the GC cleans up the channel and its content.

Comment: Why should we use and pass `done` channel? I guess only for loop with `in` channel is needed.

Answer (score 19):

It depends on your program, but generally speaking I would tend to say no (you don't need to clear the channel before closing it): if there are items in your channel when you close it, any reader still reading from the channel will receive the items until the channel is empty.

Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    var ch = make(chan int, 5)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    for range make([]struct{}, 2) {
        go func() {
            for i := range ch {
                wg.Wait()
                println(i)
            }
        }()
    }

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }
    close(ch)

    wg.Done()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

Here, the program will output all the items, despite the fact that the channel is closed strictly before any reader can even read from the channel.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the supplied answers actually do not clarify much apart from the hints that **neither drain nor closing is needed**. As such the following solution for the described context looks clean to me that terminates the workers and removes all references to them or the channel in question, thus, letting the GC to clean up the channel and its content:

```
type worker struct {
    submitted chan Task
    stop      chan bool
    p         *Processor
}

// executed in a goroutine
func (w *worker) run() {
    for {
        select {
        case task := <-w.submitted:
            if err := task.Execute(w.p); err != nil {
                logger.Error(err.Error())
            }
        case <-w.stop:
            logger.Warn("Worker stopped")
            return
        }
    }
}

func (p *Processor) Stop() {
    if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&p.status, running, stopped) {
        for _, w := range p.workers {
            w.stop <- true
        }
        // GC all workers as soon as goroutines stop
        p.workers = nil
        // GC all published data when workers terminate
        p.submitted = nil
        // no need to do the following above:
        // close(p.submitted)
        // for range p.submitted {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Your context paragraph wasn't here when I wrote my answer.

Comment: Now, using both atomic operations and sync routines feels wrong to me: you don't need to do a `CompareAndSwap`if you're going to lock right after that...

In your case, you may simply want your `Stop` method to set a boolean flag to `true`, and your workers to check that boolean to break out of their loop. That doesn't even require any syncing depending on your requirements.

Comment: @Elwinar Sorry I did not have the context when you posted your answer. I only realised it could help after I read it. With respect to your remark about locking: locking is irrelevant to this question, but here the atomic is checked on submission on new tasks (without locking) and locking is used for starting and stopping only. But thanks to your comment, I realised how I can leave it out by changing the start method (not shown here).